# Jenkins with Multistage Dockerfile replace multiple groovy scripts

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, dockerfile, sonarqube

I inherited a set up for a Jenkins pipeline that had loads of tiny groovy scripts calling one another and I've spent the past week trying to make sense of it.  I have converted part of this setup to a multi-stage Dockerfile with a build BUILD stage and a DEPLOY stage as we use a maven image for the build portion and then deploy using a lightweight Apline linux based container.

Here's where I'm stuck.  There was previously a script that just called this:

```
buildJava()
sonar()
```

**buildJava.groovy**

```
def call() {

def version = getVersion()
script { writeFile(file: "src/main/resources/version.json", text: '{"-Duser.home=/var/maven": "' + version + '"}') }

stage("Build") {
    docker.image('maven:3.6.1-jdk-11-slim').inside('-v $HOME:/var/maven -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2'){
        sh "mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package"
    }

    junit '**/surefire-reports/*.xml'
}
}
```

**sonar.groovy**

```
def call() {

stage("SonarQube Analysis") {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
        sh 'mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar'
    }
}

stage("Quality Gate") {
    timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        sleep(10)
        def qg = waitForQualityGate()
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
            error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think my hangup is on making sense of the volume (-v) in the buildJava.groovy.

My new **Dockerfile** looks like this:

```
#BUILD STAGE
FROM maven:3-amazoncorretto-11 as BUILD

COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml dependency:resolve -q

COPY src /usr/src/app/src
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

ENV MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2

VOLUME $HOME:/var/maven

#RUN STAGE
FROM docker.artifactory.mycompany.com/_base_java11:1.0 as DEPLOY

VOLUME /tmp

COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/target/*.jar app.jar
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/target/surefire-reports/ surefire-reports

# Labels
ARG GIT_VERSION=unspecified
LABEL git_version=$GIT_VERSION

# Labels
ARG JENKINS_BUILD_TAG=unspecified
LABEL jenkins_build_tag=$JENKINS_BUILD_TAG

ARG BRANCH=unspecified
LABEL branch=$BRANCH

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

CMD java -javaagent:apm-agent.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar
```

and the relevant part of the **Jenkinsfile** looks like this

```
buildImage = buildDocker(projectName, gitVersionString, deploymentEnvironment, ' --target BUILD ')

 sonar()

image = buildDocker(projectName, gitVersionString, deploymentEnvironment, ' --target DEPLOY ')
```

The sonar.groovy file is still the same as before as I'm trying to get it to remain its own part of the Jenkins pipeline.  the Jenkins build produces the dreaded

```
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.766s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 06 14:26:37 CDT 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 99M/845M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project myService: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property -> [Help 1]
```

output.  I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but it just won't come to me.  For now, I just took out the sonar() call from the Jenkinsfile and it all runs fine. Essentially, I just want to run my sonar scan where it is still its own Jenkins pipeline stage, but runs in the BUILD stage container. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**buildDocker.groovy**

```
def call(projectName, version, deployEnv, optionalArgs = '') {

    def jenkinsBuildTag = env.BUILD_TAG.replaceAll(' ', '_')

    String dockerRegistry = "docker.artifactory.mycompany.com/"

    String dockerProjectName = dockerRegistry + "prefix-" + projectName + ":" + deployEnv

    String activeSpringProfiles = getActiveSpringProfiles(deployEnv)

    newImage = ''

    stage('build docker image') {
      // build the new image defined in the Dockerfile, named whatever the value of dockerProjectName, and using the various build arguments.

       newImage = docker.build(dockerProjectName,
            "--build-arg GIT_VERSION=${version} " +
            "--build-arg JENKINS_BUILD_TAG=${jenkinsBuildTag} " +
            "--build-arg CONFIGURATION=${deployEnv} " +
            "--build-arg BUILD_ENV=${deployEnv} " +
            "--build-arg SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${activeSpringProfiles} " +
            optionalArgs +
            ".")
      
    }

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: Please show definition of buildDocker function. As SonarQube complains about missing binaries, I would suspect that your compiled code is only available within the image that gets built and not to the host where sonar runs.

Comment: @raspy Added the buildDocker.groovy file to the end of the question.  I agree completely with what you're saying...I just don't know how to go about making it available on the host where it's running.  Doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but I am stuck...

Comment: It seems to that since you already have an image returned, it should be possible to call your sonar Maven call within this image, i.e. `buildImage.inside { sh 'mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar' }`. You could probably pass the _buildImage_ as a parameter to _sonar()_.

Comment: @raspy I had assumed the same would work, but I still get the same exact. 
`Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property` error. Now I'm just wondering if it's not looking int he correct location.  in the original buildJava.groovy it was passing the `.inside('-v $HOME:/var/maven -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2')` values that I'm no longer using anywhere...

Comment: Have you tried to add `-f /usr/src/app/pom.xml`?

Comment: @raspy Progress....but now I appear to have hit some sort of permissions error. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project myProject: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock: Failed to create work directory: /usr/src/app/target/sonar -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @raspy I managed to get it to run the actual sonar scanner command by 
`USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/src/app`
at the end of my build stage in the dockerfile.  I have yet to figure out another way, because it is running as a user from the host machine that the container doesn't understand. I tried to stick a whoami in there and got
`whoami: cannot find name for user ID 988`
Anyway, the only part left is I can't get it to do the waitForQualityGate().  I had assumed wrapping both sonar stages in the same  `buildImage.inside { }` would do it, but no.

Comment: @raspy If you'll gather what you've commented into an answer, I'll accept it.Still wondering why it looks like the pipeline breaks right after the scan.
`[DEBUG] 04:18:11.134 Report metadata written to /usr/src/app/target/sonar/report-task.txt
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
...
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
...
[Pipeline] echo
caught error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to guess SonarQube task id and/or SQ server details. Please use the 'withSonarQubeEnv' wrapper to run your analysis.`